# Looping over Tuple of Btye object gives ASCII value

Tags: python-3.x

The below code in python 3 returns as

```
fro val in A:
    print (val)
```

Returns:

> [(b'3 (RFC822 {821}', b'MIME-Version: 1.0\r\nDate: Sun, 2 Feb 2020
>   22:12:19 +0530\r\nMessage-ID:
>   \r\nSubject:
>   code\r\nFrom: abc >\r\nTo: abc \r\nContent-Type:
>   multipart/alternative;
>   boundary="43434343"\r\n\r\n--0000000000008ecb2e059d9a7dfe\r\nContent-Type:
>   text/plain; charset="UTF-8"\r\n\r\n1. 4549 3867 6. 1755 6816\r\n2.
>   3068 0287 7. 8557 7000\r\n3. 3827 1727 8. 4177 1609\r\n4. 5093 4909 9.
>   9799 3366\r\n5. 1069 7992 10. 5141
>   2029\r\n\r\n--0000000000008ecb2e059d9a7dfe\r\nContent-Type: text/html;
>   charset="UTF-8"\r\n\r\ntest
>   code
> \r\n\r\n--0000000000008ecb2e059d9a7dfe--'), b')']

whereas for

```
for val in A:
    for v in val:
        print (v)
```

returns:

> b'3 (RFC822 {821}' b'MIME-Version: 1.0\r\nDate: Sun, 2 Feb 2020
>   22:12:19 +0530\r\nMessage-ID:
>   \r\nSubject:
>   code\r\nFrom: >\r\nTo: \r\nContent-Type: multipart/alternative;
>   boundary="0000000000008ecb2e059d9a7dfe"\r\n\r\n--0000000000008ecb2e059d9a7dfe\r\nContent-Type:
>   text/plain; charset="UTF-8"\r\n\r\n1. 4549 3867 6. 1755 6816\r\n2.
>   3068 0287 7. 8557 7000\r\n3. 3827 1727 8. 4177 1609\r\n4. 5093 4909 9.
>   9799 3366\r\n5. 1069 7992 10. 5141
>   2029\r\n\r\n--0000000000008ecb2e059d9a7dfe\r\nContent-Type: text/html;
>   charset="UTF-8"\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n--0000000000008ecb2e059d9a7dfe--' 41

I dont understand why i am getting ASCII Value of ')' i.e 41 and how can i just read it as ')'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would appear that when you iterate of a `bytes` object, it yields a decimal value for each byte in it:

eg:

```
>>> phrase = b'Hello, world!'
>>> chars = list(phrase)
>>> chars
[72, 101, 108, 108, 111, 44, 32, 119, 111, 114, 108, 100, 33]
```

With your example, you only have one character, so it's only one number that's printed.  The reason none of the other bytes strings are printed as integers is because they're incased in an extra tuple, so instead it's the tuple that's iterated over.

Fixing your code:

```
A = [
    (
        b'3 (RFC822 {821}',
        b'MIME-Version: 1.0\r\nDate: Sun, 2 Feb 2020 22:12:19 +0530\r\nMessage-ID: \r\nSubject: code\r\nFrom: abc >\r\nTo: abc \r\nContentType: multipart/alternative; boundary="43434343"\r\n\r\n--0000000000008ecb2e059d9a7dfe\r\nContent-Type: text/plain; charset="UTF-8"\r\n\r\n1. 4549 3867 6. 1755 6816\r\n2. 3068 0287 7. 8557 7000\r\n3. 3827 1727 8. 4177 1609\r\n4. 5093 4909 9. 9799 3366\r\n5. 1069 7992 10. 5141 2029\r\n\r\n--0000000000008ecb2e059d9a7dfe\r\nContent-Type: text/html; charset="UTF-8"\r\n\r\ntest code\r\n\r\n--0000000000008ecb2e059d9a7dfe--'
    ),
    b')'
]

for val in A:
    if isinstance(val, bytes):
        print(val)
    else:
        for v in val:
            print (v)
```

Output:

```
b'3 (RFC822 {821}'
b'MIME-Version: 1.0\r\nDate: Sun, 2 Feb 2020 22:12:19 +0530\r\nMessage-ID: \r\nSubject: code\r\nFrom: abc >\r\nTo: abc \r\nContentType: multipart/alternative; boundary="43434343"\r\n\r\n--0000000000008ecb2e059d9a7dfe\r\nContent-Type: text/plain; charset="UTF-8"\r\n\r\n1. 4549 3867 6. 1755 6816\r\n2. 3068 0287 7. 8557 7000\r\n3. 3827 1727 8. 4177 1609\r\n4. 5093 4909 9. 9799 3366\r\n5. 1069 7992 10. 5141 2029\r\n\r\n--0000000000008ecb2e059d9a7dfe\r\nContent-Type: text/html; charset="UTF-8"\r\n\r\ntest code\r\n\r\n--0000000000008ecb2e059d9a7dfe--'
b')'
```

Basically, if the object that we've encountered in `A` is a bytes-object, we print it as it is.  Otherwise (eg if it's a tuple), we iterate over it, and print its items.